# Attribute Error 'groupeddata' object has no attribute 'join' found

Tags: pyspark

> > > Here my main purpose in the code is to get all the columns from the dataframe after the group by condition but after the group by condition only the selected columns are coming.
> > > so I tried using Join condition to merge it the group by data frame with the original dataframe.
> > > But it is throwing error.

`code`

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


retail_sales_transaction = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
database="conform_main_mobconv",
table_name="retail_sales_transaction"
    
    
df_retail_sales_transaction=df_retail_sales_transaction
.select("transaction_id","transaction_key","transaction_timestamp","personnel_key","retail_site_id","personnel_role","country_code","business_week")
    
df_retail_sales_transaction = df_retail_sales_transaction.groupBy("business_week", "location_id", "country_code", "personnel_key")

df_retail_sales_transaction =df_retail_sales_transaction.join(df_retail_sales_transaction,['business_week'],'outer')
```

Error I'm getting is :

df_retail_sales_transaction = df_retail_sales_transaction.join(df_retail_sales_transaction,['business_week'],'outer')
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820994/groupeddata-object-has-no-attribute-show-when-doing-doing-pivot-in-spark-dat as similar issue. You can't use `groupby` without using another aggregate function after it. To achieve what you want, try `df_retail_sales_transaction = df_retail_sales_transaction.select("business_week", "location_id", "country_code", "personnel_key").distinct()`

Comment: Still getting the error : 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'distinct'